# How are the standard errors of coefficients calculated in a regression?

Tags: r, regression, standard-error, lm, faq

For my own understanding, I am interested in manually replicating the calculation of the standard errors of estimated coefficients as, for example, come with the output of the `lm()` function in `R`, but haven't been able to pin it down. What is the formula / implementation used?

Comment: good question, many people know the regression from linear algebra point of view, where you solve the linear equation $X'X\beta=X'y$ and get the answer for beta. Not clear why we have standard error and assumption behind it.

Comment: See also [How can I get the variance $\sigma^2$
for Linear Regression under homoscadastic with no serial correlation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/266885/248311)

Answer (score 181, accepted):

The linear model is written as
$$
\left|
\begin{array}{l}
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{\beta} + \mathbf{\epsilon} \\
 \mathbf{\epsilon} \sim N(0, \sigma^2 \mathbf{I}),
\end{array}
\right.$$
where $\mathbf{y}$ denotes the vector of responses, $\mathbf{\beta}$ is the vector of fixed effects parameters, $\mathbf{X}$ is the corresponding design matrix whose columns are the values of the explanatory variables, and $\mathbf{\epsilon}$ is the vector of random errors.

It is well known that an estimate of $\mathbf{\beta}$ is given by (refer, e.g., to [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression))
$$\hat{\mathbf{\beta}} = (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{y}.$$
Hence
$$
\textrm{Var}(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}) =
 (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime}
 \;\sigma^2 \mathbf{I} \; \mathbf{X}  (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1}
= \sigma^2 (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} (\mathbf{X}^{\prime}
 \mathbf{X})  (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1}
= \sigma^2  (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1},
$$
[reminder: $\textrm{Var}(AX)=A\times \textrm{Var}(X) \times A′$, for some random vector $X$ and some non-random matrix $A$]

so that
$$
\widehat{\textrm{Var}}(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}) = \hat{\sigma}^2  (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1},
$$
where $\hat{\sigma}^2$ can be obtained by the Mean Square Error (MSE) in the ANOVA  table.

---

**Example with a simple linear regression in R**

```
#------generate one data set with epsilon ~ N(0, 0.25)------
seed <- 1152 #seed
n <- 100     #nb of observations
a <- 5       #intercept
b <- 2.7     #slope

set.seed(seed)
epsilon <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=sqrt(0.25))
x <- sample(x=c(0, 1), size=n, replace=TRUE)
y <- a + b * x + epsilon
#-----------------------------------------------------------

#------using lm------
mod <- lm(y ~ x)
#--------------------

#------using the explicit formulas------
X <- cbind(1, x)
betaHat <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y
var_betaHat <- anova(mod)[[3]][2] * solve(t(X) %*% X)
#---------------------------------------

#------comparison------
#estimate
> mod$coef
(Intercept)           x 
   5.020261    2.755577 

> c(betaHat[1], betaHat[2])
[1] 5.020261 2.755577

#standard error
> summary(mod)$coefficients[, 2]
(Intercept)           x 
 0.06596021  0.09725302 

> sqrt(diag(var_betaHat))
                    x 
0.06596021 0.09725302 
#----------------------
```

---

When there is a single explanatory variable, the model reduces to
$$y_i = a + bx_i + \epsilon_i, \qquad i = 1, \dotsc, n$$
and
$$\mathbf{X} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & x_1 \\
1 & x_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
1 & x_n
\end{array}
\right), \qquad \mathbf{\beta} = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
a\\b
\end{array}
\right)$$
so that
$$(\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} = \frac{1}{n\sum x_i^2 - (\sum x_i)^2} 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\sum x_i^2 & -\sum x_i \\
-\sum x_i  & n
\end{array}
\right)$$
and formulas become more transparant. For example, the standard error of the estimated slope is
$$\sqrt{\widehat{\textrm{Var}}(\hat{b})} = \sqrt{[\hat{\sigma}^2  (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1}]_{22}} = \sqrt{\frac{n \hat{\sigma}^2}{n\sum x_i^2 - (\sum x_i)^2}}.$$

```
> num <- n * anova(mod)[[3]][2]
> denom <- n * sum(x^2) - sum(x)^2
> sqrt(num / denom)
[1] 0.09725302
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. So, I take it the last formula doesn't hold in the multivariate case?

Comment: No, the very last formula only works for the specific X matrix of the simple linear model. In the multivariate case, you have to use the general formula given above.

Comment: @loganecolss: It comes from the fact that $\text{Var}(AX)=A\text{Var(X)}A'$, for some random vector $X$ and some non-random matrix $A$.

Comment: note that these are the right answers for hand calculation, but the actual implementation used within `lm.fit`/`summary.lm` is a bit different, for stability and efficiency ...

Comment: This video derives the mean and variance too:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyBtfhQsf44

Comment: To be clear, `anova(mod)[[3]][2]` only works for a model with one factor, right? The "3" picks out the "Mean Sq", and the "2" picks out the "Residuals" line? Also, is that the variance of the residuals? It looks a bit different. What exactly is it?

Comment: Is another way to think of that sigma^2 as "sum-squared error of the model divided by degrees of freedom"?

Comment: Hi, when calculating the confidence interval  of the model coeffcients, do I need to divide $\sqrt{\hat{Var}(\hat{b})}$ by $\sqrt{n}$ get the standard error before multiply with critical value?

Comment: no (more characters)

Comment: +1. I have learned regression from a bayesian perspective where I assume priors on $\beta$ as gaussian and naturally the posterior on $\beta$ gives the required variance. Just to clarify my understanding, I assume the above analysis is about the frequentist viewpoint?

Comment: @swag2198: yes, parameter uncertainty is readily available from the posterior in the bayesian analysis.

Comment: Commenting from the future here for anyone who got stuck on the first equal of the variance formula: $Var(\hat{\beta}) = Var((X^\prime X)^{-1}X^\prime y) = (X^\prime X)^{-1}X^\prime Var(y)X(X^\prime X)^{-1}$. And it just happens that $Var(y) = Var(\epsilon)$

Comment: What is the formula for $\hat{\sigma}^2$?

Answer (score 37):

The formulae for these can be found in any intermediate text on statistics, in particular, you can find them in [Sheather (2009, Chapter 5)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387096078), from where the following exercise is also taken (page 138).

The following R code computes the coefficient estimates and their standard errors manually

```
dfData <- as.data.frame(
  read.csv("https://gattonweb.uky.edu/sheather/book/docs/datasets/MichelinNY.csv",
                   header=T))

# using direct calculations
vY <- as.matrix(dfData[, -2])[, 5]                        # dependent variable
mX <- cbind(constant = 1, as.matrix(dfData[, -2])[, -5])  # design matrix

vBeta <- solve(t(mX)%*%mX, t(mX)%*%vY)                    # coefficient estimates
dSigmaSq <- sum((vY - mX%*%vBeta)^2)/(nrow(mX)-ncol(mX))  # estimate of sigma-squared
mVarCovar <- dSigmaSq*chol2inv(chol(t(mX)%*%mX))          # variance covariance matrix
vStdErr <- sqrt(diag(mVarCovar))                          # coeff. est. standard errors
print(cbind(vBeta, vStdErr))                              # output
```

which produces the output

```
                         vStdErr
constant   -57.6003854 9.2336793
InMichelin   1.9931416 2.6357441
Food         0.2006282 0.6682711
Decor        2.2048571 0.3929987
Service      3.0597698 0.5705031
```

Compare to the output from `lm()`:

```
# using lm()
names(dfData)
summary(lm(Price ~ InMichelin + Food + Decor + Service, data = dfData))
```

which produces the output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Price ~ InMichelin + Food + Decor + Service, data = dfData)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-20.898  -5.835  -0.755   3.457 105.785 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -57.6004     9.2337  -6.238 3.84e-09 ***
InMichelin    1.9931     2.6357   0.756    0.451    
Food          0.2006     0.6683   0.300    0.764    
Decor         2.2049     0.3930   5.610 8.76e-08 ***
Service       3.0598     0.5705   5.363 2.84e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 13.55 on 159 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.6344, Adjusted R-squared: 0.6252 
F-statistic: 68.98 on 4 and 159 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Nice trick with the `solve()` function. This would be quite a bit longer without the matrix algebra. Is there a succinct way of performing that specific line with just basic operators?

Comment: @AkselO There is the well-known closed form expression for the OLS estimator, $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = (\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{Y}$, which you can compute by explicitly computing the inverse of the $(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})$ matrix (as @ ocram has done), but this gets tricky with ill-conditioned matrices.

Comment: The book website is now at http://gattonweb.uky.edu/sheather/book/.

Comment: The link does not seem to contain data

Answer (score 1):

Part of Ocram's answer is wrong.
Actually:

$\hat{\mathbf{\beta}} = (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{y} - (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{\epsilon}.$

$E(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}) = (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{y}.$

And the comment of the first answer shows that more explanation of variance of coefficient is needed:

$\textrm{Var}(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}) = E(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}-E(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}))^2=\textrm{Var}(- (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{\epsilon})
=(\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime}
 \;\sigma^2 \mathbf{I} \; \mathbf{X}  (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1}
= \sigma^2  (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1}$

---

### Edit

Thanks, I $\mathbf{wrongly}$ ignored the hat on that beta. The deduction above is $\mathbf{wrong}$. The correct result is:

1.$\hat{\mathbf{\beta}} = (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{y}.$ (To get this equation, set the first order derivative of $\mathbf{SSR}$ on $\mathbf{\beta}$ equal to zero, for maxmizing $\mathbf{SSR}$)

2.$E(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}|\mathbf{X}) = E((\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} (\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\beta}+\mathbf{\epsilon})|\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{\beta} + ((\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime})E(\mathbf{\epsilon}|\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{\beta}.$

3.$\textrm{Var}(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}) = E(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}-E(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}|\mathbf{X}))^2=\textrm{Var}((\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{\epsilon})
=(\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime}
 \;\sigma^2 \mathbf{I} \; \mathbf{X}  (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1}
= \sigma^2  (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1}$

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: The derivation of the OLS estimator for the beta vector, $\hat{\boldsymbol \beta} = ({\bf X'X})^{-1}{\bf X'Y}$, is found in any decent regression textbook. In light of that, can you provide a proof that it should be $\hat{\mathbf{\beta}} = (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{y} - (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{\epsilon}$ instead?

Comment: Your $\hat\beta$ is not even an estimator, because $\epsilon$ is not observable!

Comment: This can also be viewed in this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyBtfhQsf44