# How to derive the standard error of linear regression coefficient

Tags: standard-error, inference

For this univariate linear regression model
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i+\epsilon_i$$
given data set $D=\{(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)\}$, the coefficient estimates are 
$$\hat\beta_1=\frac{\sum_ix_iy_i-n\bar x\bar y}{n\bar x^2-\sum_ix_i^2}$$ $$\hat\beta_0=\bar y - \hat\beta_1\bar x$$
Here is my question, according to the book and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Normality_assumption), the standard error of $\hat\beta_1$ is $$s_{\hat\beta_1}=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_i\hat\epsilon_i^2}{(n-2)\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)^2}}$$
How and why?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44838/how-are-the-standard-errors-of-coefficients-calculated-in-a-regression/44841#44841

Comment: @ocram, thanks, but I'm not quite capable of handling matrix stuff, I'll try.

Comment: @ocram, I've already understand how it comes. But still a question: in my post, the standard error has $(n-2)$, where according to your answer, it doesn't, why?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

3rd comment above: *I've already understand how it comes. But still a question: in my post, the standard error has (n−2), where according to your answer, it doesn't, why?*

---

In [my post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44838/how-are-the-standard-errors-of-coefficients-calculated-in-a-regression/44841#44841),  it is found that
$$
\widehat{\text{se}}(\hat{b}) = \sqrt{\frac{n \hat{\sigma}^2}{n\sum x_i^2 - (\sum x_i)^2}}.
$$
The denominator can be written as
$$
n \sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2
$$
Thus,
$$
\widehat{\text{se}}(\hat{b})  = \sqrt{\frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2}}
$$

With
$$
\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n-2} \sum_i \hat{\epsilon}_i^2
$$
i.e. the Mean Square Error (MSE) in the ANOVA table, we end up with your expression for $\widehat{\text{se}}(\hat{b})$. The $n-2$ term accounts for the loss of 2 degrees of freedom in the estimation of the intercept and the slope.

Comment: I think I get everything else expect the last part. Can you show step by step why $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n-2} \sum_i \hat{\epsilon}_i^2$ ? I too know it is related to the degrees of freedom, but I do not get the math.

Answer (score 3):

another way of thinking about the n-2 df is that it's because we use 2 means to estimate the slope coefficient (the mean of Y and X)

df from Wikipedia: "...In general, the degrees of freedom of an estimate of a parameter are equal to the number of independent scores that go into the estimate **minus the number of parameters used as intermediate steps in the estimation of the parameter itself** ."

Comment: This isn't really a derivation as such, though it is an intuition. For some subtleties related to this, though, see [How to understand degrees of freedom?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16921/22228)