# The Standard Error in R language lm (linear regression) is Standard Deviation or Standard Error of the Mean?

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, standard-deviation, standard-error

When we are estimating the coefficient in R, "Std Err" will be produced by "lm". Is it Std or SEM? How is it calculated? Run lm function with any R data set will give an example.

Comment: I think R returns the estimated standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
           Coefficients:
                         Estimate  Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
             (Intercept)  0.02224    0.03189   0.697    0.486
                 x       -0.03747    0.03214  -1.166    0.244
```

If you mean the column with header `Std. Error`, then it is the estimated standard error of estimated regression coefficients.

Comment: Thank you! Is it standard deviation? What is the formula used to determine the Std. Error?

Comment: When you cannot figure out you should call it standard error or standard deviation, you can just call its square as **variance**. The appear of standard error or standard deviation statistics is disaster. For calculation, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85943/how-to-derive-the-standard-error-of-linear-regression-coefficient