# Calculating standard error of coefficients in segmented regression

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, standard-error, segmented-regression

Consider the following equation resulted from segmented regression:
$$\hat y_i = \begin{cases}
\hat\beta_1 x_i + (\hat\beta_0 - \hat\beta_1 \cdot c) &\text{if } x_i \le c \\
\hat\beta_2x_i + (\hat\beta_0 - \hat\beta_2 \cdot c)&\text{else}\end{cases}$$
where $c$ is the break point and $i = 1,2,\ldots n$.
And according to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85943/how-to-derive-the-standard-error-of-linear-regression-coefficient), standard error of linear regression coefficient can be calculated as follows:
$$\hat y_i = \hat\beta x_i + b,\ i = 1,2,\ldots n\\
\widehat{\text{se}}(\hat{\beta})  = \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{n-2} \sum_i \hat{\epsilon}_i^2}{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2}}
$$
Now if I want to calculate the standard error of $\hat\beta_1$ from segmented regression, will it be this: $$\widehat{\text{se}}(\hat\beta_1) = \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{N-2} \sum_i \hat{\epsilon}_i^2}{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2}}$$
where $i$ is index of $x_i$ such that $x_i \le c$ and $N$ is number of $x_i$ such that $x_i \le c$? Or do I have to use all $i$ (i.e the whole data set) to calculate standard error of $\hat\beta_1$?

Comment: The fitted parameter does not apply to the entire data set, so the associated standard error also does not apply to the entire data set.