# What is the Std.error parameter in the result when using the summary function in regression?

Tags: r, regression

I use R for programming but when I use the summary function on a regression, there is one parameter that is **Std. Error**, which I don't understand. What is it?

[image: Please click here]

Comment: I suggest you get yourself a basic textbook on regression. Googling "standard error of regression coefficients" should also yield some useful results.

Comment: For what a standard error is, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error). In this case you're dealing with the standard error of the coefficient estimate (i.e. of the intercept or slope, respectively)

Comment: It is an estimate of the scale of uncertainty in the coefficients.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85943/how-to-derive-the-standard-error-of-linear-regression-coefficient shows how it is calcuated