# What is the 1 standard deviation error in papers

Tags: regression, standard-deviation, linear, error

I have recently come across some papers in my field. They had a large (X,Y) data set, it was binned into 4 bins. Least square method was used to find slope (m) and y intercept (b). In the table that contains the slope and y intercept they include what they call "1 standard deviation error" for each of the m and b. My question is what is this error and was it obtained?

Link to paper
Second page table 1 and figure 1

https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.05544

Comment: Can you link the paper? That would help

Comment: It sounds like they are referring to the standard errors of the estimates for the intercept and slopes. These are standard outputs from statistical software and allow you to compute confidence intervals for these parameters, as well as obtain p-values for them. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85943/how-to-derive-the-standard-error-of-linear-regression-coefficient

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Although the paper doesn't appear to explain its fitting method, the figure makes it clear these are ordinary least-squares fits (for the logged variables).  The "$\sigma$ values" would of course be the standard errors as routinely output by any least-squares fitting algorithm.

Comment: How are these standard errors computed for the slope and intercept?

Comment: @Axxxxx see the link in my previous comment

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=compute+regression+standard+error.