# Estimating standard error of parameters of linear model fitted using gradient descent

Tags: regression, least-squares, standard-error, gradient-descent

Given a linear model

$$y = X\beta + \epsilon$$

we can estimate parameters $\hat{\beta}$ using two different ways - **ordinary least squares** (OLS) and **gradient descent** (GD). Both of them boil down to minimizing mean squared error (MSE) by finding its global minimum. The difference is that while OLS finds exact solution, GD iteratively approaches it, but may never find exact answer.

For OLS we have usual set of parameter estimates, most notably **standard error** $SE(\hat{\beta})$. But in some cases OLS is not an option (e.g. data matrix is too large), so we have to use GD.

I'm trying to figure out:

1. Does it make sense at all to **apply SE** to parameters learned using **gradient descent**?
2. If so, **how do we calculate it**? Do other dependent things like t-statistic and significance test take the usual form?
3. What about **stochastic gradient descent** (SGD)? Is there any hope to assess its parameters?

---

For common reference:

- [How are the standard errors of coefficients calculated in a regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44838/how-are-the-standard-errors-of-coefficients-calculated-in-a-regression) [OLS]

Comment: You could maybe use the profile likelihood near the optimum to get the individual standard errors.

Comment: Thanks, @Glen_b, it seems to be a good approach. Though, I need to upgrade my skills in this area, so I'll take some time to learn more about profile likelihood and hopefully come back with complete solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that **bootstrap** gives estimates that are pretty close to those from OLS, but works with literally *any* training algorithm.

Bootstrap is a kind of Monte Carlo method and roughly boils down to **repeated sampling with replacement** from original dataset and **collecting values of a target statistic**. Having a set of statistic values, it becomes trivial to calculate their mean and standard error. G. James et al. provide experimental evidence of closeness of OLS and bootstrap results. Without further explanation, I'm giving a link to their excellent work (see pages 187-190 for bootstrap explanation and 195-197 for experiments):

- [G. James et al. An introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/)