# How are the standard errors of coefficients derived in a regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics

I'm seeking a little help understanding the derivation of the standard error of the coefficients in linear regression. Most of the derivation has already been documented in the answers by ocram to [How are the standard errors of coefficients calculated in a regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44838/how-are-the-standard-errors-of-coefficients-calculated-in-a-regression), but there is one step I can't follow.

As background, we have the model:
$$
\left|
\begin{array}{l}
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{\beta} + \mathbf{\epsilon} \\
 \mathbf{\epsilon} \sim N(0, \sigma^2 \mathbf{I}),
\end{array}
\right.$$

And we calculate (a):

$$
\widehat{\textrm{Var}}(\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}) = \hat{\sigma}^2  (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1},
$$

Using (b):

$$\hat{\mathbf{\beta}} = (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{y}.$$

And (c):

$$
{\textrm{Var}}({\mathbf{Ay}}) = \mathbf{A}{\textrm{Var}}({\mathbf{y}}) \mathbf{A}^{\prime},
$$

Where (d):

$${\mathbf{A}} = (\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime}$$

---

From (c) & (d), I can tell that ${\textrm{Var}}({\mathbf{y}})$ must be an [$n$ by $n$] matrix.

But ${\mathbf{why}}$ is the Variance of a vector with dimension $n$ defined as an [$n$ by $n$] matrix?

I'm getting stuck on the following issues:

(1) What is the definition of ${\textrm{Var}}({\mathbf{y}})$?

(2) Why does it need to be defined that way (and why is it $n$ by $n$)?

(3) How does one calculate it?

(4) What is the general result of that calculation in this case?

I hope that these are easy questions to answer for someone versed in multi-variable statistical theory.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix

Comment: You are asking two different things.  Do you want the Var(${\bf y}$), which is the variance-covariance matrix of the responses (and is, by model assumptions, equal to the n by n matrix ${\bf \sigma^2 I}$).  Is it the variance of ${\it one}$ observation, so that it is, by definition, $\sigma^2$?  Or is it (as per your title) the standard errors of the coefficients, which you obtain by taking the square root of each variance of a coefficient, which in turn are the diagonals of ${\bf \sigma^2 (X'X)^{-1}}$?

Comment: I see your point. Thanks. I'm now just looking for intuition about the use of $Var(y)$.  And I've now started to get comfortable with it based on mark999's recommendation to read Wikipedia on "Covariance_matrix".