# How do you derive the formula for the variance of $\hat Y$ in OLS regression

Tags: regression, variance, least-squares

I know how to find it for the regression slope, and also that $Var(Y_i)$ is $\sigma^2$, but what is $Var(\hat Y)$?

Comment: try writing $Var(\hat Y) = Var(X\hat \beta)$ and use what you know about $\hat \beta$. Does this help?

Comment: Add self study tag.

Comment: Related: [How are the standard errors of coefficients calculated in a regression?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/44838/12359)