# How to calculate standard erorr of beta's for multiple regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, standard-deviation, standard-error

If you only have
$y_i = \hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1} x_i + \hat{\epsilon_i}$ ,
Then $\hat{\sigma}_{\beta_1} = \sqrt{ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \hat{\epsilon}_i} {(n-2)(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x}))} }$

Say
$y_i = x_i\hat{\beta} + \hat{\epsilon}$, where x is a row vector of features and $\beta$ is a column vector of betas.

How would we calculate standard error for each beta?

Comment: There are squares missing in your formula. See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44838/how-are-the-standard-errors-of-coefficients-calculated-in-a-regression/44841#44841

Comment: Many more answers are available by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multiple+regression+standard+error+answers%3A1).